Can I tunnel HTTPS requests through a Node.js proxy server, using node-fetch without extra modules?
I have a HTTP proxy server like so
ProxyServer = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  console.log("connection established");
  console.log("request", request);

  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('okay');
});

I can tunnel HTTPS requests via http.request with method: 'CONNECT', based off this example https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-connect, but I would like to see if I could use node-fetch the handle the requests.
All the examples I was able to find online rely on the module https-proxy-agent, but I would like to avoid using other modules. So I tried setting up an http Agent myself
const proxyAgent = new http.Agent({
  keepAlive: true, 
  maxSockets: 10, 
  keepAliveMsecs: 1000, 
  timeout: 5000, 
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 3000,
  protocol: 'http:'
});

I also tried initiating the Agent connection before making the fetch request
proxyAgent.createConnection(agent_options, () => {
  console.log("Agent connection established");

  agent.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Agent disconnected from server');
  }); 
})

And then making the fetch request
const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/ip?json', { agent: proxyAgent });
const body = await response.text();
console.log(body);

But I get an error

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "https:" not supported.
Expected "http:"

Is it possible to tunnel HTTPS requests via a Node.js HTTP proxy with a custom Agent?
